# How to prevent multiple consumers of a topic from acting on a message at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, cluster-computing, hazelcast

I searched for a good pattern to implement here, and couldn't find anything.

First, I have multiple nodes in a cluster subscribing to a topic. Because I am interfacing with an external API, I cannot change this topic to a queue (which would solve my problems). When a message goes into this topic, the subscribers react, but I need to ensure that only one subscriber actually does any work.

I have multiple nodes for durability and for scalability. I thought about just electing a master node, but over time there will be multiple topics, and I do not want to make only one node responsible for all messages all the time. Hazelcast is not a requirement here.

```
@Named
public class MessageProcessorImpl
    implements MessageProcessor
{

  HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

  private final Lock lock;

  private final List<Message> messageListCache;

  private final IAtomicLong cachePositionCounter;

  private final Long maximumRecentlyProcessedCachedSize = 10L;

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageProcessorImpl.class);

  private final ExternalMessageService externalMessageService;

  @Inject
  public MessageProcessorImpl(final ExternalMessageService externalMessageService)
  {
    lock = hazelcastInstance.getLock("test-lock");
    messageListCache = hazelcastInstance.getList("test-list");
    cachePositionCounter = hazelcastInstance.getAtomicLong("test-atomic-long");

    this.externalMessageService = externalMessageService;
  }

  @Override
  public void processMessage(final Message message) {
    try {
      logger.trace("Acquiring lock");
      lock.lock();
      if (!messageListCache.contains(message)) {

        Long currentIndex = cachePositionCounter.getAndIncrement();
        if (currentIndex >= maximumRecentlyProcessedCachedSize) {
          currentIndex = 0L;
          cachePositionCounter.set(currentIndex);
        }

        messageListCache.add(toIntExact(currentIndex), message);

        externalMessageService.doSomething(message);
      }
    }
    finally {
      logger.trace("releasing lock");
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am using a list of recently processed message to prevent duplicate work. The problem here is obvious, what if that list is overwhelmed. I could set that cache relatively high, but not infinite so the list doesn't grow forever. Also, there is some overhead to checking whether a message is in a list.

Is there a better solution or a way I could avoid the edge case of that list being overwhelmed and causing duplicate work? I'm not even sure if that's a valid concern, it's difficult to reason about. Is there a different approach I should try?

Comment: Couldn't you just create multiple topics and assign each node a topic? On publishing you just select a random topic or you go round robin. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: @noctarius - unfortunately I can not. The topic is provided to me by a third-party web sockets API with which I am integrating.

Comment: No middle layer possible? Collecting all messages from the topic and forwarding it to a queue (like using Apache Camel + Hazelcast adapter)?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very late. However, the pattern that might help in this case is leadership election. That is one node is elected to process a message from the topic while others wait till the message is processed successfully. The leadership changes with each message.

Apache Zooker has facility for distributed lock/leadership election, refer [here](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/recipes.html#:%7E:text=own%20ephemeral%20node.-,Leader%20Election,with%20both%20flags%20SEQUENCE%7CEPHEMERAL.)